# set value of custom field after creation from sale order partner id

Tags: odoo-10

i have creating a custom field in odoo and want to set a value as it get from partner id  field below is the function iam using to get the value help me in this regard

model code

```py
  from odoo import models,fields,api 

  class SaleOrderInherited(models.Model): 
  _inherit = 'sale.order' 

  #custom_field = fields.Char(string='Custom Field') 

  def _get_default_access_token(self): 
  #return str(uuid.uuid4()) 
     return "testing" 
  #custom_field = fields.Char(string='Custom Field',default) 
  custom_field=fields.Text(string="Registration Note",default=_get_default_access_token)
```

view code

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<odoo> 
    <data> 
        <record id="sales_view_form" model="ir.ui.view"> 
          <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/> 
          <field name="model">sale.order</field> 
          <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/> 
          <field name="arch" type="xml"> 
              <field name="date_order" position="after"> 
                <!--<field name="custom_field"/>--> 
              </field> 
         </field> 
        </record> 
    </data> 
</odoo>
```

Error in the code field not found

Comment: Please can you elaborate more,

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have 'sale' in the list of the 'depends' in your **openerp**.py file.
Then try this in your xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<odoo> 
    <data> 
        <record id="sales_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">  
          <field name="model">sale.order</field> 
          <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/> 
          <field name="arch" type="xml"> 
              <xpath expr="//*/field[@name='date_order']" position="after"> 
                <field name="custom_field"/> 
              </xpath> 
         </field> 
        </record> 
    </data> 
</odoo>
```